# Python - select row cell based on another cell condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am writing some python to draw a pie chart. I am attempting to find how many goals were scored using a certain formation. The format of each row is:

```
date        home_team      away_team home_score away_score  home_formation  away_formation
14/06/2018  Russia      Saudi Arabia         5           0         4-2-3-1         4-1-4-1
```

What I would like to do it say if the home team has the formation 4-2-3-1, add the home_score to the counter. At the end I will display these goals into a pie chart

```
for x in df:
if df.home_formation == '4-1-4-1':
    counter += df.home_score

formationScore1 = counter
```

My question: How do I go through a CSV file, check if the formation is that one I want and add that rows score to the variable

Comment: You appear to be using a dataframe, can you `groupby` home_formation and `.sum()` on home_score?

Comment: It has an issue at the if statment:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What about not looping at all? Something like `df.groupby('home_formation').sum()['home_score']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formations = ['4-1-4-1', '4-2-3-1']  #Add as many as you'd like

formation_scores = {formation: df[df['home_formation'] == formation]['home_score'].sum() for formation in formations}
```

Comment: Legend! The way the conditioning is done in python confuses me and alot of the online sources suggest the if statment.... Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: @JoeG If it helps you research, this filtering is specific to certain objects in python including numpy arrays and pandas dataframes, and it is called Boolean Masking

Answer (score 0):

Pandas supports grouping operations natively. For example, using `groupby`:

```
scores_by_formation = df.groupby('home_formation')['home_score'].sum()
```

If you require scores for only specific formations, you can filter your dataframe first:

```
L = ['4-1-4-1', '4-2-3-1']

scores_by_specific_formations = df.loc[df['home_formation'].isin(L)]\
                                  .groupby('home_formation')['home_score'].sum()
```

Via these operations, you are taking advantage of vectorised NumPy functionality and avoiding an explicit Python-level loop.